# C# regex groups trouble

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am sorry for may be stupid question, but I cannot solve little problem and cannot find the same question in google. So, I thought to write here. I need to parse the same strings:

```
string line = "HELLO MYNAME IS1 = {P 111.11, O -222.22, L 333.33, L -444.44, Y 555.55}";
```

My code for that is:

```
string line = "HELLO MYNAME IS1 = {P 111.11, O -222.22, L 333.33, L -444.44, Y 555.55}";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^HELLO MYNAME ([A-Za-z0-9]+) = {([A-Z]\s[+-]?[0-9]+.[0-9]+,?\s?)+}");
MatchCollection matchCollection = re.Matches(line);
foreach(Match m in matchCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: ");
    foreach(Group gr in m.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No {gr.Index} Value: {gr.Value}");
    }
 }
```

But I cannot understand why output looks like this:

Match:

No 0 Value: HELLO MY NAME IS1 = {P 111.11, O -222.22, L 333.33, L -444.44, Y 555.55}
No 13 Value: IS1
No 62 Value: Y  555.55

I am sorry again, can you explain to me why only the last group goes to result.

Comment: You can use [`(?:^HELLO MYNAME (\w+) = {|\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*)([A-Z]\s[+-]?\d+\.\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5eHELLO+MYNAME+%28%5cw%2b%29+%3d+%7b%7c%5cG%28%3f!%5cA%29%5cs*%2c%5cs*%29%28%5bA-Z%5d%5cs%5b%2b-%5d%3f%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29&i=HELLO+MYNAME+IS1+%3d+%7bP+111.11%2c+O+-222.22%2c+L+333.33%2c+L+-444.44%2c+Y+555.55%7d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should grab Group 1 value to get the value captured with the first capturing group, and get all *captures* captured with the second capturing group:

```
string line = "HELLO MYNAME IS1 = {P 111.11, O -222.22, L 333.33, L -444.44, Y 555.55}";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^HELLO MYNAME ([A-Za-z0-9]+) = {([A-Z]\s[+-]?[0-9]+.[0-9]+,?\s?)+}");
MatchCollection matchCollection = re.Matches(line);
foreach(Match m in matchCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: ");
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    foreach (Capture cap in m.Groups[2].Captures)
        Console.WriteLine($"No {cap.Index} Value: {cap.Value}");
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/okS98B)

Output:

```
Match: 
IS1
No 20 Value: P 111.11, 
No 30 Value: O -222.22, 
No 41 Value: L 333.33, 
No 51 Value: L -444.44, 
No 62 Value: Y 555.55
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about it

Answer (score 2):

By definition a repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.
Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations :

```
^HELLO MYNAME ([A-Za-z0-9]+) = {(([A-Z]\s[+-]?[0-9]+.[0-9]+,?\s?)+)}
```

Comment: C# doesn't just capture the final match. C# actually keeps all captures.

Comment: @ctwheels, Yes, you're right C# doesn't. I know. I was adressing the general  EMCA group capture implementation.